# Batch script for replacing the same file from one folder to another folder

Tags: batch

I have two folders where in src folder contains the original files and the destination folder contains the modified files. I want to replace the original file with the modified file which will have the same name. For example :

**src fodler**

C:\Users\admin\Desktop\101-modified\2009-5201215\5176123\5201043\5201215\html--- This contains art.html,ref.html

**destination folder**

D:\qc-testing\5201215--  This also contains art.html,ref.html.

So i want to replace the originals with modified files for all the folders in "101-modified" using a batch script.Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Please read [ask] to better understand how this site works. This isn't a place to make requests to have someone write a script for you. [Edit] your question to share with us what you've already tried and where you ran into a problem.

Comment: @elgonzo if this is a duplicate, use the [close] under the question feature to mark it as such.

Comment: @CharlieRB He does not have enough reputation to see the Close option.

Comment: @Moses Thanks. {palm on forehead} I forget about that sometimes.